# count an attribute of a coupled table

Tags: python, odoo

I want to count the sales that a seller has related, I have used len and search_count but the method does not work for me. I currently have a table called a document in which I buy and sell the products there. So I want him to only tell me the sales I make and not buy them. When using the len, he tells me about purchases and sales, therefore it does not work for me.
the code is the following:

```
class Document (models.Model):

    total_document_sales = fields.Float (string = "Total sale")

class Seller (models.Model):

    sales_counter = fields.Integer (string = "Sales made", compute = "get_sales_realized")

    document_ids = fields.One2many (asdel_name = 'project_rc.document', inverse_name = 'worker_id', string = 'Invoice')

##The method using the len is as follows:

def get_sales_realized (self):

    for rec in self:

        rec.sales_counter = len (rec.document_ids.total_document_sales)

##The method using the search_count is as follows:##

@api.depends (document_ids)

def get_sales_realized (self):

    count = self.env ['project_rc.document.ids']. search_count ([('total_document_sales', '=', self.document.ids.total_document_sales)])

    self.sales_counter = count
```

but neither of me finds it. Help me please.

Comment: Is there an attribute we can use in search_count to distinguish between sales and purchases?

Comment: if there is an attribute and it is total_document_sales that is in the document table, since there all the sales of a person are combined, for example: a person bought 2 screws and 5 spark plugs in total sales, the total amount of money from those purchases will come out. That would already count as 1 purchase and if another person goes and buys the same or something else is another purchase then the counter would be 2.

Comment: So you want to set `sales_counter` to the sum of `total_document_sales ` of each document in `document_ids`?

Comment: I want you to count the sales made based on total_document_sales, since it is the only attribute that I have that interacts with the sales and thus does not count the purchases.